# Is there a version of matrix rank that can take non-whole values?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

The rank of a matrix $A$ can be viewed as the number of linearly independent columns of said matrix. For example 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $r=1$ and the column space spans a line contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Numerically speaking matrix $B$ is "almost" the same as $A$:
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1.01 \\
    2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, strictly speaking, matrix B has rank $r=2$, as its columns spans the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ space. Even though its rank is 2, in an informal way we could say that B has  a rank $R$ "almost 1" ($R \approx 1$ or maybe $1<R<2$) due to the fact that its second column is very close to its first column.

Is there some sort of continuous "rank" $R$ (with values that are not necessarily positive integers but are from $\mathbb{R}$) that captures this property?

Another way of restating the question: is there a generalization of the notion of dimension of a vector space that is not necessarily a positive integer? I suspect fractal theory might offer some insight.

Comment: The determinant varies continuously and is close to $0$ when a square matrix is close to not have full-rank.

Comment: Actually, the determinant is a very poor way of measuring closeness to singularity.  Take a matrix of size 10 by 10, with determinant 0.1.  Now multiply the matrix by 0.001 and compute the determinant.  The scaled matrix isn't any closer to being singular, but the determinant is now tiny.

Answer (score 1):

The non-zero singular values and associated singular vectors of a matrix $A$ determine the dimensions and orthogonal bases for $R(A)$, $R(A^{T})$, $N(A)$, and $N(A^{T})$.  You can set a tolerance below which a singular value should be considered effectively 0 and use that to determine the numerical rank.